# Prevent self retain cycle in combine flatMap

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, combine

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create a Swift Combine pipeline that contains a `.flatMap` which has a reference to `self`. In order to prevent a retain cycle, this should be a `[weak self]` reference, but this does not work with a `.flatMap`.

Here is a simplified example showing my problem:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class SomeService {
    func someOperation(label: String) -> Future<String, Never> {
        Future { promise in
            print("Starting work for", label)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                print("Finished work for", label)

                promise(.success(label))
            }
        }
    }
}

class SomeDataSource {
    let someService = SomeService()
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    deinit {
        print("Deinit SomeDataSource")
    }
    
    func complexOperation() {
        // First part 'defined' is inside the complexOperation method:
        someService.someOperation(label: "First part")
            // Second part is 'defined' in another method (it is shared with other tasks)
            .flatMap { _ in self.partOfComplexOperation(label: "Second part") } // <--- This creates a retain cycle
            .sink { label in
                print("Received value in sink", label)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func partOfComplexOperation(label: String) -> Future<String, Never> {
        someService.someOperation(label: label)
    }
}

var someDataSource: SomeDataSource? = SomeDataSource()
someDataSource?.complexOperation()
someDataSource = nil
```

Output:

```
Starting work for First part
Finished work for First part
Starting work for Second part
Finished work for Second part
Received value in sink Second part
Deinit SomeDataSource
```

The problem here is that I want my `SomeDataSource` to be deinitialised right after starting the "First part" and not even starting the second part. So the output I'm looking for is:

```
Starting work for First part
Deinit SomeDataSource
Finished work for First part
```

I'm looking for some kind of combination of `.flatMap` and `.compactMap`. Does this exist? If I first `.compactMap { [weak self] _ in self }` I get the expected result, but maybe there is a better way?

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class SomeService {
    func someOperation(label: String) -> Future<String, Never> {
        Future { promise in
            print("Starting work for", label)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                print("Finished work for", label)

                promise(.success(label))
            }
        }
    }
}

class SomeDataSource {
    let someService = SomeService()
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    deinit {
        print("Deinit SomeDataSource")
    }
    
    func complexOperation() {
        // First part 'defined' is inside the complexOperation method:
        someService.someOperation(label: "First part")
            .compactMap { [weak self] _ in self }
            // Second part is 'defined' in another method (it is shared with other tasks)
            .flatMap { dataSource in dataSource.partOfComplexOperation(label: "Second part") }
            .sink { label in
                print("Received value in sink", label)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func partOfComplexOperation(label: String) -> Future<String, Never> {
        someService.someOperation(label: label)
    }
}

var someDataSource: SomeDataSource? = SomeDataSource()
someDataSource?.complexOperation()
someDataSource = nil
```

Output:

```
Starting work for First part
Deinit SomeDataSource
Finished work for First part
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution here is to not retain self. You don't even want self in the flatMap so why retain it...

```
let label = someService.someOperation(label: "First part")
    .flatMap { [someService] _ in 
        someService.someOperation(label: label)
    }
```

Of course seeing all this work on `someService` implies that the service is missing some functionality. Seeing that the result of `someOperation` is being ignored might also be a red flag.

If you were truly in a situation where you *had* to use self, then the solution would look like this:

```
let foo = someOperation()
    .flatMap { [weak self] in 
        self?.otherOperation() ?? Empty(completeImmediately: true)
    }
```

Or you might consider something like:

```
someOperation()
    .compactMap { [weak someService] _ in
        someService?.otherOperation()
    }
    .switchToLatest()
```

Which will cancel `otherOperation()` if a new event comes through from `someOperation()`.

Comment: `Empty` doesn't work by itself. It requires to specify a concrete type